# How to get swap reporting data from repositories ICE and CME?

Tags: data, swaps

[Bloomberg](http://www.bloombergsdr.com/slicefiles) and [DTCC](https://rtdata.dtcc.com/gtr/dashboard.do) both release swap reporting data in form of downloadable files which can be analyzed later on. I have been looking for the same on ICE and CME sites, but couldn't find.

How can I download the swap reporting data from these two swap data repositories?